# Do Reports and Leaves in Coop vs AI Count?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering: can someone get punished for leaving coop games? Or even for raging or doing whatever to get himself reported in general.

I know this isn't the case in Custom Games but i'm not sure about coops because for example if you dodge a coop game you still have to wait just like in any normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This game mode is still considered a matchmaking game. Only Custom Games have different rules. So all reports and penalties which would apply in a normal or ranked game will apply here as well!

Comment: Is there an official statement where riot states that they punish offenders from Coop vs AI games? I mean I'm almost with you there, but for example when you dodge a normal queue game you get a 5 minute wait and then a 15 minute wait (if you do it a second time). In ranked you get a 5 minute wait and then a 30 minute wait. So there are differences between those 2 modes. I'm guessing there will be differences between normal games and coop games. It makes sense that there will be.

Comment: https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20030633-Leaving-Games-The-Leaver-Buster-FAQ Here, the FAQ states: `Are ranked, normal, and co-op games treated differently?

Double penalties are issued for idling/leaving ranked games.` That's the reason you get double penalty for ranked games, but the normals/coop are treated the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to check is right after the game do you see the report button beside the user like you see in normal and ranked game? If so then definitely yes, you can be reported.

Comment: Of course you can see it. You can see the report button next to players even in custom games. But we all know custom games are not taken into consideration by Riot. So this doesn't really prove anything unfortunately. :(

Comment: hmm really.. looks like that is a bug they need to fix :)

Comment: No that's not a bug. If a player acts undesirably, that player should be reported. It doesn't matter where or how he does that.

Comment: since OP stated that custom games are not taken into consideration by Riot which means the report button after those game does nothing then what I mean is that this is a bug that needed to be fixed.